# Why is it my application which contains DWM thumbnail lags when the target app was moved to second monitor?

Tags: wpf, gpu, cpu, multiple-monitors, dwm

Scenario:
I have a wpf fullscreen borderless application that displays a live thumbnail of a borderless, fullscreen UWP app that plays video.

My laptop setup includes 1 extended monitor thru HDMI port.

My wpf app can display a live thumbnail of the target app very well without lag.

But the problem occurs when I move the target UWP app to the second screen, my wpf app that contains DWM thumbnail is lagging and stuck on a single frame.

Hypothesis:
It could be the graphics adapter/ or native video source thru HDMI. Because if I move the target UWP app back to primary screen my wpf app is working well.
Also if I use miracast for second display instead of HDMI, still my app works well without lag.

Is there any known workaround for this? or anyone has the same problem? How did you fix it?

thanks!